# Run external program on gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a linux program that can read one file, and write to other. In.txt is created by jsp. How can I run the console application to automatically create out.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to run shell commands in an environment which allows you full control.  AppEngine is not a VPS, it's a sandboxed service platform.  Google Compute Engine does allow you full control, but a micro EC2 might be more to your budget's liking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run external applications on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine

Currently, the supported programming languages are Python, Java (and, by extension, other JVM languages such as Groovy, JRuby, Scala, Clojure, Jython and PHP via a special version of Quercus), and Go.

=> If your application is written in one of this languages, there might be a chance